# Having white border on text background

Tags: html, css

I'm a student who is making some money for my uni in a few moths. I never had direct experience with html or css. It has been mostly a hobby.

I am trying to make a deadline, which has a red background. I don't know why, but I have white borders at the text line at the sides. But more annoying is, the border on the top, there should not be a border or white space at all.

It's probably something easy, would you please have a look?
Edit: Forgot to tell you I can only use css ot=r html, no Javascript.

---

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Standart.css"> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id='headline'>
<h1> Test </h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,400);

#headline {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #e31f36;


}

#bild {

}

#bildweg {


}


#menueoben {


}
```

Comment: I think its something client wise, I just tested your code in jsFiddle and its fine! http://jsfiddle.net/1g1pdqbc/

Comment: Try adding `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;} h1 {margin: 0;}` in your CSS.

Comment: I also created a jsFiddle, and it's fine.  I added body { background-color: BLACK }; to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, `h1` tags (and many other tags) have inherited styles. You can remove the padding/margins with a reset:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdzzdxu8/)

```
body, html {
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I would suggest using a full CSS reset such as: [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: But its now even adding my normal text at the top, is this normal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Removing the padding on the `html, body` will remove all that space. I would apply the margins/padding to the elements rather than the body.

Comment: Why change all the h1 tags? Not just the one in the header?

Comment: For predictability and consistency. Each browser may handle each tag differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this at the top of your CSS file:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

This resets all the browser differences and I got it from here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue with white borders around your text but to fix your white space issue add this to your css

```
body{margin: 0;}
#headline > h1 {margin-top: 0px;}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g1pdqbc/1/

Answer (score 0):

This works ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wtjs22pc/1/)):

```
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#headline h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: NO!!!! why not select only the h1 tag that is in the header and not all on the page?

Comment: Thank you. I cannot believe how many people answered the question that way. Much better now!

Comment: but adding `body{margin: 0;}` will still be less code :)